# Why is extended stylesheet not rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Brand new project. react-native-extended-stylesheet installed. everything working fine, and then out of nowhere it stops working. here's the full component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, FlatList, View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const data = [
    {
        title: 'Johnny Appleseed',
        subtitle: 'November 12, 2019',
        img: require('./src/assets/img/johnny_appleseed.png'),
        type: 'video'
    },
    {
        title: 'Johnathan Doe',
        subtitle: 'November 19, 2019',
        img: require('./src/assets/img/johnny_appleseed.png'),
        type: 'voice'
    }
];

const AgendaItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
                    <Image
                        resizeMethod={'scale'}
                        source={
                            props.type === 'voice' ? (
                                require('./src/assets/img/voice_icon.png')
                            ) : (
                                require('./src/assets/img/video_icon.png')
                            )
                        }
                        style={styles.icon}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{props.subtitle}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <Image source={props.img} style={styles.img} />
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const ProfileList = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <AgendaItem title={item.title} subtitle={item.subtitle} img={item.img} type={item.type} />
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
    $rem: width > 380 ? 18 : 16,
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 25,
        elevation: 3,
        marginBottom: 5,
        width: '22rem',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        marginHorizontal: '0.5rem',
        paddingVertical: '.75rem',
        paddingHorizontal: '1.5rem'
    },
    textContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    },
    leftContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#454A66'
    },
    subtitle: {
        color: '#454A66',
        fontSize: 12
    },
    img: {
        height: '3rem',
        width: '3rem',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#169C75',
        borderRadius: 30
    },
    icon: {
        height: '1.5rem',
        width: '1.5rem'
    }
});

export default ProfileList;
```

I was just messing with some of the properties and all of a sudden it stopped rendering any style in the styles object. ive tried closing/opening the project. ive tried rebooting system. this just seems buggy because its happened before.

any suggestions or something I missed?